# Dynamically check whether a particular app is installed or not in android

Tags: android, tracking, ads

I want to know whether the user have installed the apps from the links i provided in my application..

The problem is the package name,
first I have to install the app to get to know the app package name, and then write the code which compares with the package name i provided.

I cant do this process for each and every new app promotion.

Is there a way to know the package name of the android apps without even installing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the App on the Play Store.

The package name is in the URL... For example:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dae.dfnews

The important part is `id=dae.dfnews`. `dae.dfnews` is the package name.

Comment: Thanks all for the replay :)

Answer (score 1):

If your user installs the app from Google play store then your links should look something like this

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=**com.example.app**

or in case of play store app prompt like this

> market://details?id=**com.example.app**

the last part (id) should actually be the package name